# Qt get directory of opened file with

Tags: c++, qt

I made a notepad that works really fine using Qt framework. When I open a file using QFileDialog and get the path of the file, it's fine. But when I open a file from FileBrowser, the QTextEdit is empty. I think it's totally normal, because I didn't get the path of the opened file. This is exactly what I need, how to get the opened file path and stock it in a QString. Is there a way to get it in Qt? I heard about argv but I didn't know how to use it and I didn't find a documentation. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I think that needs some more clarification. What are the two cases? In the second scenario, you open your file with QFileDialog and put the content into a QTextDialog and how do you do this in your first scenario? And do you use Windows notepad here or is that just also the name for your app?

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#arguments

Comment: Thanks for your alert! I corrected it.

Comment: But I didn't understand the Arguments, can you give me an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to read application arguments. The simplest way is to check if there is something passed and then interpret the first argument as a file name e.g.:

```
QString fileUrl;
if(argc > 1)
    fileUrl = QString(argv[1]);
```

Or:

```
QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);
QString fileUrl;
if(app.arguments().length() > 1)
    fileUrl = app.arguments()[1];
```

Yet in Qt there's a more flexible solution using [QCommandLineParser](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcommandlineparser.html) e.g.:

```
QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);
QCommandLineParser parser;
parser.addPositionalArgument("url", "Url of file to open");
parser.process(app);
QString fileUrl;
if(parser.positionalArguments().length() > 0)
    fileUrl = parser.positionalArguments()[0];
```

The last solution is more flexible because it will be easy to add other command line options to the application.